# How to compare two array of object and if value are same add new key: value on second object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's take an example. I've two array of objects

```
let paymentType = [
  {id: "settle", set: "dis_10"},
  {id: "settle1", set: "dis_20"},
  {id: "settle2", set: "dis_30"},
]
```

```
let result = [
  {id: "settle", type: 40},
  {id: "settle4", type: 50},
  {id: "settle2", type: 60},
]
```

If id from both array matches I want to add the the set value to the result array of object.
Final result will be

```
let result = [
  {id: "settle", type: 40, set: "dis_10"},
  {id: "settle4", type: 50},
  {id: "settle2", type: 60},
]
```

I've tried using filter and some method, but didn't work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might be something that you are looking for if I understood your question well

```
 result.forEach((item) => {
      if (paymentType.find((el) => el.id == item.id))
        item.set = paymentType.find((el) => el.id == item.id).set;
    });
```

This will result in

```
[
    {
        "id": "settle",
        "type": 40,
        "set": "dis_10"
    },
    {
        "id": "settle4",
        "type": 50
    },
    {
        "id": "settle2",
        "type": 60,
        "set": "dis_30"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) everything to a single accumulator object keyed by `id`, and then get the [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) from that:

```js
const paymentType = [
  {id: "settle", set: "dis_10"},
  {id: "settle1", set: "dis_20"},
  {id: "settle2", set: "dis_30"},
];

const result = [
  {id: "settle", type: 40},
  {id: "settle4", type: 50},
  {id: "settle2", type: 60},
];

const merge = (...arrays) => Object.values(
  arrays.reduce((a, array) => array.reduce((a, v) => {
    a[v.id] = { ...(a[v.id] || {}), ...v };
    return a;
  }, a), {})
);

console.log(merge(paymentType, result));
```

This has a linear runtime complexity (`O(n)`), as opposed to solutions that invoke `find()` or `findIndex()` on every iteration which are `O(n log n)` at best.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:

```js
const paymentType = [
  {id: "settle", set: "dis_10"},
  {id: "settle1", set: "dis_20"},
  {id: "settle2", set: "dis_30"},
];

let result = [
  {id: "settle", type: 40},
  {id: "settle4", type: 50},
  {id: "settle2", type: 60},
];

result.forEach((resultItem, index) => {
  const id = resultItem.id;
  // Chech if the id exists in the paymentType array
  const paymentTypeIndex = paymentType.findIndex((paymentTypeItem) => paymentTypeItem.id === id);
  if(paymentTypeIndex > -1) {
    // If the id exists, we add the paymentType item values to the result item.
    resultItem.set = paymentType[paymentTypeIndex].set;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```